# Scipy's N-dimensional interpolation with "sparse=True" produces unexpected ValueError

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am working on an n-D interpolation example using `scipy.interpolate.interpn`. The toy example code below works correctly, as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(4)
y=np.arange(3)
z=np.arange(2)
xx = np.linspace(0, 3, 7)
yy = np.linspace(0,2, 5)
zz = np.linspace(0,1,3)
a1=np.arange(24)
a1=a1.reshape((4,3,2))

grids=np.array(np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij'))   
grids=np.moveaxis(grids, 0, -1)
a2=interpn((x,y,z), a1, grids)
```

However, if I 
change 
    `grids=np.array(np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij'))`
to

```
    grids=np.array(np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, sparse=True, indexing='ij'))
```

I got `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`, which points to

> /home/zell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy-1.4.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py(2645)interpn()

The issue seems to be introduced by "sparse=True".
How can I work around this problem while still keeping "sparse=True" (because my grids will take much memory)?

Answer (score 2):

`meshgrid` makes 3 array, one for each input array.  Without `sparse`, each is a 3d array, the same shape:

```
In [95]: len(np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij'))                                                              
Out[95]: 3
In [96]: np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij')[0].shape                                                          
Out[96]: (7, 5, 3)
```

When you wrap that in `np.array` you get a (3, 7, 5, 3) array.

With `sparse`, it makes 3 arrays, 3d also, but not full.  They broadcast together in the same way, but don't have repeated elements

```
In [97]: np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij', sparse=True)[0].shape                                             
Out[97]: (7, 1, 1)
In [98]: np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij', sparse=True)[1].shape                                             
Out[98]: (1, 5, 1)
In [99]: np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij', sparse=True)[2].shape                                             
Out[99]: (1, 1, 3)
```

You can't turn those into one 4d array as before!

In newest 1.19dev I get this warning:

```
In [101]: np.array(np.meshgrid(xx,yy,zz, indexing='ij', sparse=True)).shape                                     
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an 
ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of 
lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is 
deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' 
when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[101]: (3,)
```

It's this 3 element object dtype array that's giving `interpn` problems.

`interpn` docs specify the `xi` argument as

```
 xi - ndarray of shape (…, ndim)
The coordinates to sample the gridded data at
```

Clearly it expects are regular numpy array, not a 'ragged' one.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed explanation. What would be a work-around then? As mentioned in the post, I have to retain "sparse=True" because the grids in use is too big in memory.

Comment: Write you own version of `interpn` !

Comment: @hpaulj Can any other interpolation function in scipy work around this problem?